# QGIS Georeferencer adds padding to image after save

Tags: gdal, georeferencing, qgis-2.6

I am attempting to georeference an aerial image using satellite imagery. I'm successful in getting an output, however I notice there is an issue where QGIS's georeferencer is adding padding to all the edges around the image after the save. It looks like it's related to the gdal_warp command (as I separated out the commands from the georeferencer); I'm using a polynomial 2 with cubic spline resampling method with a total of 6 GCPs. The target SRS is EPSG:4326. Attached is an illustration of what I mean: 
[image: Image pointing out crop padding]

It's important to have this not require any human cropping as the human will not be perfect in generating the proper output.

Here's the zoomed out view to give the full picture with the georeferenced on on the left and the original on the right again:
[image: Full view]

Comment: I believe that warping process is rotating the image a bit and what you call extra padding cannot be avoided. Notice that the corners of the original image are somewhere in the white area and they can't be seen. I still believe that they are touching the border of the warped image.